# Parse4cn1 connection error

Tags: codenameone, parse4cn1

I'm facing trouble using parse4cn1 because apparently I have a connection issue with the server(back4app). I was working with parse4cn1 for quite some time and everything went fine until yesterday. Right now I am getting a ParseException when using it -

[parse4cn1] Request failed.

ParseException [code=100, msg=Connection to backend failed., cause=null]

**The project runs perfectly on a different pc. tried to use another network on this computer and still get the same connection issue.
It must be my computer blocking me from using this particular server. unfortunately I do not know how to check if this is true and obviously how to fix it..(am using netbeans if it matters..)

help would be apreciated!

Itay

Comment: I would check with back4app maybe you crossed a quota limit. I'd also suggest checking the network monitor to see what request/responses are going in and out

Comment: The network monitor is empty, even the initial request is not showing up.

Comment: Try checking if your computer is blocking that particular IP:
 http://forums.devshed.com/dev-shed-lounge-26/windows-deny-hosts-605256.html

Comment: Is that true for the computers where that works too?

Comment: Again, on another computer it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually the issue was in my codename1 simulator, apparently the default behavior of it is blocking all outgoing network connections (or at least that how it was for me). I had to simply change it to regular network activity.